# How to fix the "recursive gc invocation" error

Tags: r, dataframe, csv

I have a list of dataframes called "df_list_2" and I'm trying to convert these dataframes into the format "excel_csv" and then I'd like to put them in a path in my computer. But this error comes up :

```
     wrote 7.16kB in  0s, 106.80MB/s *** recursive gc invocation
     *** recursive gc invocation
     *** recursive gc invocation
     *** recursive gc invocation
     *** recursive gc invocation
```

This is my code so far:

```
  myfiles_full_names= list.files(path="/mypath", pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)

  myfiles_trend_name <- list.files(path="/mypath", pattern = "*.csv") |> stringr::str_remove(".csv")


  df_list_2<-lapply(myfiles_full_names , function(x) read.csv(x, sep=","))

   for (i in seq_along(df_list_2)) {
   readr::write_excel_csv(df_list_2[[i]], 
   paste0("where I want to put the csv files/",names(df_list_2)[i] ,".csv"))
     }
```

Each dataframes in the list has three colomuns "Date" (class POSIXct), "id" (class numeric) and "Text" (class character)

Comment: Do you use RStudio ? There seems to be a bug with some version: https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-fix-recursive-gc-invocation-followed-by-rstudio-crash/127607/11

Comment: Yes, I'm using RStudio